# Pyinstaller .exe da malfuncionamientos que .py no, crea infinitas copias de la ejecución

Tags: python, tkinter, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

tengo un malfuncionamiento de mi programa en al usar el .exe que creo con Pyinstaller pero no al ejecutarlo con .py, el programa consiste de una interfaz de tkinter con 6 Label que dan información de 6 Entry y dos Botton al final que ejecutan un mismo método pero con diferente argumentos, el problema consiste en que una vez se ejecuta en .exe en lugar de ejecutar ese método correctamente, vuelve a crear una instancia del mismo tkinter que hay, con sus mismos Labe, Entry y Botton que al pulsarlos tambien crea otra instancia, mientras que el .py funciona perfectamente, es un solo .py sin importar otros .py creados por mi, pero tiene imports de Selenium, tkinter, threading, os, re, json, time, datetime, xlsxwriter.

Puede que sea temas de que Pyinstaller no este detectando alguno de los imports, porque he leído que eso era un problema, pero no he visto a nadie con un problema tan especifico como el mío, agradezco sugerencias de lo que podría probar a continuación, o y también si alguien tiene la solución a mi problema, o piensa que es necesario poner alguna información que facilite la identificación y solución de este problema.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo, este es mi primer post de pregunta, por si hay algo que no esta bien.

EDIT:
A petición añado textos con todo lo que pone el CMD si se abre .exe por CMD,[CMD solo habiendo iniciado por CMD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nFbNcSUerK5hvj2mCq0aP8Qg3BO2_Yx0/view?usp=sharing), [CMD habiendo clicado una vez en uno de los dos botones](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LIQhtMkqiSpdeQEmCfiwzOQE6G-n9qVS/view?usp=sharing) Si vosotros notáis algún error, podríais comentármelo por favor.

Comment: Puedes intentar ver si ocurre un error abriendo el exe con cmd. Si aparece un error, podrías agregarlo a la pregunta por favor?

Comment: Si lo abro por CMD solo me salen Imports, puede que yo me este saltando algún error que no he visto, pero pondré el texto de todo lo que me sale una vez iniciado y habiendo clicado una vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para todo el que entre, ya tengo la solución, busque en un foro ingles y lo encontré.

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support() # Lo unico que se tiene que añadir es esta linea
    inicioWSRC()
```

Creo que añade un control de procesos o algo así, me lo tengo que leer mas a fondo, pero al menos es una solución que me ha funcionado a mi, y puede que ayude a alguien mas.